# Unable to login to sonarqube as admin/admin?

Tags: sonarqube

Have installed sonarqube and MYSQL database in linux server and able to access the sonar dashboard from windows machine. But when I try to login as admin/admin, it is throwing error as authentication failed and I am not able to login. But I can able to see the user admin in the USERS table. Could you please help me as what I am missing here ?

Comment: Why version of SonarQube are you using ? Is it the first installation ? Are you using a proxy ?

Comment: Did you try to reset the password? You have only to execute `update users set crypted_password = '88c991e39bb88b94178123a849606905ebf440f5', salt='6522f3c5007ae910ad690bb1bdbf264a34884c6d' where login = 'admin'` (read [more here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Authentication))

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam I am experiencing the exact same problem with a fresh install of 7.1 in kubernetes.  Any ideas?  I've done the whole reset as mentioned by agabrys

Comment: I need more log to investigate : what is the exact error status/message ? Are there any ERROR in web.log ?

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam : The problem seems to have disappeared.  I suspect I had an ingress problem.